# php xml read access xml object always 0

Tags: php, xml, object, simplexml

This code behaves different on my system as on for example codepad and i don't understand why.

http://codepad.org/jBmXRgyY

The output on my system is only 0.

Does anyone know where to look?

Comment: What does `print_r($xmldata->elements[1]['name']);` return?

Comment: Can you post the xml string here?

Comment: $xmldata->elements[1]->name should give you the desired results but I guess you are pointing to an empty index. Try to print the elements array again.

Comment: Come on man, I told you so many times whats wrong with your code. Now there is another  `print_r($xmltest->element[1]->display-name);` : what's `display-name` there? its plain `name`. Im going to delete my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a workaround by myself.

```
foreach($chstr->channel->children() as $test)
    echo (string)$test."\n";
```

works fine for me.